# VtigerAsteriskConnector, incoming AGI failed 'Premature end of file'

Tags: asterisk, vtiger, vtigercrm, elastix

Appreciate your support in integrating vtiger asterisk connector (no incoming call popup nor click-to-call) with Elastix 4 (Asterisk 11.20), vtiger 7.1, and 
java version:

```
java version "10.0.1" 2018-04-17

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10, mixed mode)

Elastix & vtiger are on same server

VtigerAsteriskConnector.properties:

ServerIP   = 192.168.1.2

ServerPort = 8282

StorageDir = /var/www/html/VtigerAsteriskConnector/storage

Recording = true

AsteriskAppDBPath = /var/www/html/VtigerAsteriskConnector/storage

AsteriskServerPublicIP = 192.168.1.2

AsteriskServerIP   = 192.168.1.2

AsteriskServerPort = 5038

AsteriskUsername   = xxxxxxxx

AsteriskPassword   = xxxxxxxx

VtigerURL = https://192.168.1.2/vtigercrm/

VtigerSecretKey = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

AsteriskLog = true

DatabaseLog = true
```

vTiger configurations:

```
Vtiger Asterisk App URL: https://192.168.1.2:8282

Outbound Context: vtiger-outbound

Outbound Trunk: dahdi1

Vtiger Secret Key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

extensions.conf:

```
[from-internal]

include => from-internal-noxfer

include => from-internal-xfer

include => bad-number ; auto-generated
//add connector agi

exten => _X.,1,Agi(agi://127.0.0.1/incoming.agi)
```

When test incoming internal call from extension 102 to crm user extension (103), no incoming call popup fired as AGI failed with 'Premature end of file' error, extension 102 call hang-up after 3 seconds and doesn't ring at 103, call logged at PBX manager with ringing status and later status updated to no-response, when click record, error fired 'Record you are trying to access is not found'

WebappInfo.log:

```
[INFO] 2018-06-14 14:57:07 a a Database connection successfull

[INFO] 2018-06-14 14:57:08 a a INSERT INTO vtiger_webapp_asterisk(uid,srcuid,event,channel,from_number,context,callertype,direction) VALUES(003a6ee9d1ee4913a45af4f4d74a681d,1528981025.647,AgiEvent,SIP/102-000000cf,102,from-internal,SIP,inbound);

[INFO] 2018-06-14 14:57:08 a a Successfully inserted data -> AgiEvent

[INFO] 2018-06-14 14:57:08 a a SELECT uid FROM vtiger_webapp_asterisk WHERE srcuid =1528981025.647 OR destuid =1528981025.647;

[INFO] 2018-06-14 14:57:08 a a Event: AgiEvent->003a6ee9d1ee4913a45af4f4d74a681d

[INFO] 2018-06-14 14:57:08 b a VtigerURL: https://192.168.1.2/vtigercrm/modules/PBXManager/callbacks/PBXManager.php

[INFO] 2018-06-14 14:57:08 b a Sending HTTP request to Vtiger

AgiInfo.log:

[INFO] 2018-06-14 14:57:05 a log Asterisk Login Successfull

[INFO] 2018-06-14 14:57:05 org.asteriskjava.manager.internal.ManagerConnectionImpl info Connecting to 192.168.1.2:5038

[INFO] 2018-06-14 14:57:05 org.asteriskjava.manager.internal.ManagerConnectionImpl info Connected via Asterisk Call Manager/1.3

[WARN] 2018-06-14 14:57:05 org.asteriskjava.manager.internal.ManagerConnectionImpl warn Unsupported protocol version 'Asterisk Call Manager/1.3'. Use at your own risk.

[INFO] 2018-06-14 14:57:05 org.asteriskjava.manager.internal.ManagerConnectionImpl info Successfully logged in

[INFO] 2018-06-14 14:57:05 org.asteriskjava.manager.internal.EventBuilderImpl info No event class registered for event type 'fullybooted', attributes: {privilege=system,all, event=FullyBooted, status=Fully Booted}. Please report at http://jira.reucon.org/browse/AJ

[INFO] 2018-06-14 14:57:07 org.asteriskjava.manager.internal.ManagerConnectionImpl info Determined Asterisk version: Asterisk 1.6

[INFO] 2018-06-14 14:57:07 a log org.asteriskjava.manager.event.ConnectEvent[dateReceived='Thu Jun 14 14:57:07 EET 2018',server=null,protocolidentifier='Asterisk Call Manager/1.3',sequencenumber=null,timestamp=null,systemHashcode=1470855628]

[INFO] 2018-06-14 14:57:07 b log Sending HTTP request to webapp

[INFO] 2018-06-14 14:57:07 IncomingCall log Started Manager Event

[WARN] 2018-06-14 14:57:07 org.asteriskjava.manager.internal.EventBuilderImpl warn Unable to set property 'connectedlinename' to '<unknown>' on org.asteriskjava.manager.event.StatusEvent: no setter. Please report at http://jira.reucon.org/browse/AJ

[INFO] 2018-06-14 14:57:07 b log Sending HTTP request to webapp

[WARN] 2018-06-14 14:57:07 org.asteriskjava.manager.internal.EventBuilderImpl warn Unable to set property 'connectedlinenum' to '<unknown>' on org.asteriskjava.manager.event.StatusEvent: no setter. Please report at http://jira.reucon.org/browse/AJ

[INFO] 2018-06-14 14:57:07 a log org.asteriskjava.manager.event.StatusEvent[dateReceived='Thu Jun 14 14:57:07 EET 2018',privilege='Call',server=null,calleridname='102',extension='103',link=null,channel='SIP/102-000000cf',seconds='2',calleridnum='102',context='from-internal',actionid=null,callerid='102',state='Up',uniqueid='1528981025.647',channelstatedesc='Up',timestamp=null,variables=null,internalactionid='493765340_6',bridgedchannel=null,priority='1',sequencenumber=null,channelstate='6',bridgeduniqueid=null,accountcode=null,account=null,systemHashcode=2098591697]

[INFO] 2018-06-14 14:57:07 b log Sending HTTP request to webapp

[INFO] 2018-06-14 14:57:07 a log org.asteriskjava.manager.event.StatusCompleteEvent[dateReceived='Thu Jun 14 14:57:07 EET 2018',server=null,internalactionid='493765340_6',sequencenumber=null,actionid=null,items='1',timestamp=null,systemHashcode=248508687]

[INFO] 2018-06-14 14:57:07 b log Sending HTTP request to webapp

[FATAL] 2018-06-14 14:57:08 com.vtiger.apps.asterisk.agi.b.c a 
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:257)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
    at com.vtiger.apps.asterisk.agi.b.c.a(SourceFile:48)
    at com.vtiger.apps.asterisk.agi.actions.IncomingCall.process(SourceFile:55)
    at com.vtiger.apps.asterisk.agi.actions.IncomingCall.service(SourceFile:26)
    at org.asteriskjava.fastagi.internal.AgiConnectionHandler.runScript(AgiConnectionHandler.java:144)
    at org.asteriskjava.fastagi.internal.AgiConnectionHandler.run(AgiConnectionHandler.java:116)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)

[INFO] 2018-06-14 14:57:08 org.asteriskjava.manager.internal.EventBuilderImpl info No event class registered for event type 'softhanguprequest', attributes: {channel=SIP/102-000000cf, cause=32, privilege=call,all, event=SoftHangupRequest, uniqueid=1528981025.647}. Please report at http://jira.reucon.org/browse/AJ

[FATAL] 2018-06-14 14:57:08 IncomingCall log 

[FATAL] 2018-06-14 14:57:08 IncomingCall log Failed to authenticate Vtiger Secret Key

[INFO] 2018-06-14 14:57:08 a log Logging off from Asterisk

[INFO] 2018-06-14 14:57:08 org.asteriskjava.manager.internal.ManagerReaderImpl info Terminating reader thread: No more lines available: null

[INFO] 2018-06-14 14:57:08 org.asteriskjava.manager.internal.ManagerConnectionImpl info Closing socket.

[INFO] 2018-06-14 14:57:08 IncomingCall log Exiting from agi script

[INFO] 2018-06-14 14:57:08 org.asteriskjava.fastagi.internal.FastAgiConnectionHandler info End AgiScript com.vtiger.apps.asterisk.agi.actions.IncomingCall on Asterisk-Java DaemonPool-1-thread-1
```

I switched to Elastix 2.4 (Asterisk 1.8.20.0), and still have same error.
java version:
java version "1.8.0_171"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)

AgiError.log
[WARN] 2018-06-18 07:18:00 org.asteriskjava.manager.internal.EventBuilderImpl warn Unable to set property 'connectedlinename' to '' on org.asteriskjava.manager.event.StatusEvent: no setter. Please report at http://jira.reucon.org/browse/AJ
[WARN] 2018-06-18 07:18:00 org.asteriskjava.manager.internal.EventBuilderImpl warn Unable to set property 'connectedlinenum' to '' on org.asteriskjava.manager.event.StatusEvent: no setter. Please report at http://jira.reucon.org/browse/AJ
[FATAL] 2018-06-18 07:18:01 com.vtiger.apps.asterisk.agi.b.c a
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:257)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
        at com.vtiger.apps.asterisk.agi.b.c.a(SourceFile:48)
        at com.vtiger.apps.asterisk.agi.actions.IncomingCall.process(SourceFile:55)
        at com.vtiger.apps.asterisk.agi.actions.IncomingCall.service(SourceFile:26)
        at org.asteriskjava.fastagi.internal.AgiConnectionHandler.runScript(AgiConnectionHandler.java:144)
        at org.asteriskjava.fastagi.internal.AgiConnectionHandler.run(AgiConnectionHandler.java:116)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[FATAL] 2018-06-18 07:18:01 IncomingCall log
[FATAL] 2018-06-18 07:18:01 IncomingCall log Failed to authenticate Vtiger Secret Key

Answer (score 1):

Vtiger connector works only with asterisk 1.8

Yes, they know

No, then don't care about.

No, there are no source of that module availible, so no way to fix.

But you can read PBXManager module and create your own dialplan to do same. 
Expected time for expert 5-10hrs.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your support.

vtiger connector documentation said it supports asterisk 1.8 onward
https://wiki.vtiger.com/vtiger6/index.php/Asterisk_Integration

Plz, provide details for "you can read PBXManager module and create your own dialplan"

BR,

Comment: vtiger documentation lie. It not work 100% correct even in next version(11.*)

Comment: find in vtiger directory directory PBXManager(after install pbxmanager like described in vtiger doc), read source code or hire expert.

Comment: Dear @arheops,
I switched to Elastix 2.4 (Asterisk 1.8.20.0), and still have same error.

java version:
java version "1.8.0_171"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)

Comment: Elastix 2.4 is short way for loose money by hack. Check dependency like described on wiki(log2java etc).

Comment: Dear @arheops,
Sorry, what do you mean by "Check dependency like described on wiki(log2java etc)", I googled without success.
BR,